# is it Is possible to add multiple values within one parameter of a class?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

I’m new to flutter I was wondering if it Is possible to add multiple values within one parameter of a class?

For example for parameter storePageItemPrice, storePageItemName and storePageImage, I want to be able to add multiple prices, item names and multiple product pictures in each store.

How can I achieve this?

Example

```
class Stores {
String storeName;
String storeImage;
String storeDeliveryTime;
String deliveryCharges;
String storePageImage;
String storePageItemName;
String storePageItemPrice;

Stores.list({this.storeName, this.storeDeliveryTime, 
this.storeImage,this.deliveryCharges,this.storePageImage, 
this.storePageItemName, this.storePageItemPrice});
 }

List<Stores> storesList = [

Stores.list(
storeName: “STORE 1”,
storeImage: "assets/images/STORE1FRONT”,
storeDeliveryTime: "25 min",
deliveryCharges: "£3.90",
storePageImage: “BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE IMAGE“ (and then build 
widget.storePageImage),
storePageItemName: “BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE ITEM“,(and then 
build widget.storePageItemName),
storePageItemPrice: "BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE PRICE”(and then 
build widget.storePageItemPrice),

),

Stores.list(
storeName: “STORE 2”,
storeImage: "assets/images/STORE2FRONT",
storeDeliveryTime: "25 min",
deliveryCharges: "£2.90",
storePageImage: “BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE IMAGE“ (and then    
build widget.storePageImage),
storePageItemName: “BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE ITEM“,(and then 
build widget.storePageItemName),
storePageItemPrice: "BE ABLE TO ADD MORE THAN ONE PRICE”(and then 
build widget.storePageItemPrice),
),
];
```

Visual example; Here is the home page https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbj7F.jpg

Once a restaurant has been clicked it navigates to restaurant’s page(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ4X0.jpg) where multiple items have been added (can be added and removed on demand once connected to database)

first page code

```
ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 1000),
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: storesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: (){Navigator.of(context).push(new 
MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => new StoresPage(
                          storeName: storesList[index].storeName,
                          storeDeliveryTime: 
storesList[index].storeDeliveryTime,
                          deliveryCharges: 
storesList[index].deliveryCharges,
                          storePageImage: 
storesList[index].storePageImage,
                          storePageItemName: 
storesList[index].storePageItemName,
                          storePageItemPrice: 
storesList[index].storePageItemPrice,
                        )));},
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0),
                      child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: 205,
                              width: 380,
                              child: Image(image: 
AssetImage(storesList[index].storeImage),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 
15.0, right: 15.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: 
MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                Text(storesList[index].storeName),
                                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                                    Icon(Icons.update, size: 20.0),

Text(storesList[index].storeDeliveryTime),
                                  ],
                                  ),
                              ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Navigates to storespage

```
class StoresPage extends StatefulWidget {
String storeName;
String storeDeliveryTime;
String deliveryCharges;
List<String> storePageImage;
List<String> storePageItemName;
List<String> storePageItemPrice;

StoresPage({
this.storeName, this.storeDeliveryTime, this.deliveryCharges, 
this.storePageImage, this.storePageItemName, this.storePageItemPrice
});

List<Stores> storesList = [
newStore1,
newStore2,
];
```

This code didn't work

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 7.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                        image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fill,image: 
AssetImage(widget.storePageImage()))
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

I tried to use this code in stores page but nothing happened

```
ConstrainedBox(constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 1000),
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: storesList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 7.0),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              image: DecorationImage(fit: 
BoxFit.fill,image: 
AssetImage(storesList[index].storePageImage.toString()))
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: The error I get is Error: 'storePageImage' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.
                            image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fill,image: AssetImage(widget.storePageImage()))

Answer (score 0):

### Ensure properties are typed as List

```dart
class Stores {
  String storeName;
  String storeImage;
  String storeDeliveryTime;
  String deliveryCharges;
  List<String> storePageImage;
  List<String> storePageItemName;
  List<double> storePageItemPrice;

  Stores.list({this.storeName, this.storeDeliveryTime, 
  this.storeImage,this.deliveryCharges,this.storePageImage, 
  this.storePageItemName, this.storePageItemPrice});
}
```

#### Later you can create instance by this

```dart
Stores newStore1 = Stores.list(
  storeName: "STORE 1",
  storeImage: "assets/images/STORE1FRONT",
  storeDeliveryTime: "25 min",
  deliveryCharges: "£2.90",
  storePageImage: ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"],
  storePageItemName: ["Apple", "Mango"],
  storePageItemPrice: [100, 200],
);

Stores newStore2 = Stores.list(
  storeName: "STORE 2",
  storeImage: "assets/images/STORE2FRONT",
  storeDeliveryTime: "25 min",
  deliveryCharges: "£2.90",
  storePageImage: ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"],
  storePageItemName: ["Apple", "Mango"],
  storePageItemPrice: [100, 200],
);


List<Stores> storesList = [
  newStore1,
  newStore2,
]
```

#### How to render it ?

since we need to render multiple images, therefore we will need to multiply all of its parent.

Its definitions of Padding, Container, BoxDecoration, DecorationImage must be rendered in several times.

[image]

#### Output

this is my result with my flower images.

### *Update 25 Aug

**This is fix to your latest code version**

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Restauran Menus")),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var storeImage in storePageImage) // loops storePageImage
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 7.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      image: AssetImage(storeImage),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

#### Full Code

look into this repo [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/b_screen/image_card_store_update.dart)

### Latest Demo

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I put widget.storePageImage or widget.storePageImage, or widget.storePageItemPrice it doesn't work. What am I supposed to do to make it work? because for the other ones it works with no problem. I've added code to my question to make it more understandable

Comment: The error I get is Error: 'storePageImage' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked. image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fill,image: AssetImage(widget.storePageImage()))

Comment: since we need to render multiple images, therefore we will need to multiply all of its parent.

Its definitions of Padding, Container, BoxDecoration, DecorationImage must be rendered in several times. 

I updated my answer above

Comment: for exploring more image-rendering methods, please look at this https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/tree/master/docs/b_screen

Comment: It doesn't work, because the problem is that the same images come to all stores, but each store requires its own images even though they have already been given their own images in the data file

Comment: yes, because previously I put this `Stores selectedStore = storesList[0];` so it will only displays for first store. I did that because I did not know how did you setup the trigger. Now, I completed my example in the full repo

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve in terms of UI, https://imgur.com/a/k24I6CP, but with the code I'm getting this https://imgur.com/a/Ju895Ps GIT: https://github.com/MFVictory/flowerstores/tree/master/lib